# Custom Cell Renderer

Tags: java, tablecellrenderer

Is it possible to create an instance of custom cell renderer and put different values in it, for each column, depending on the arguments given to it ?

For example:

[image: Calendar]

I have this renderer (`MyCustomCellRenderer myRen = new MyCustomCellRenderer`), and for each column I put a different argument to display something difeerent in the `ComboBox`:

```
MyCustomCellRenderer myRen = new MyCustomCellRenderer
for (int i = 0; i < table.nbColumns; i++) {
  myRen.setArg(myArg); //denpending on this argument I fill the combo
  myJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(myRen);
}
```

How can I do this?

**Edit**:

Looks like there is a missunderstanding, I have my list of arguments and I wrote the code above as example.

My question is : What should I write in `MyCustomCellRenderer` class to make the renderer changes everytime for each column ?
**My renderer class:**

```
public class MyCustomCellRenderer extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTextField hs = new JTextField();
    private Activity aObj = new Activity();
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private JComboBox<ComboItem> activityCombo = new JComboBox(aObj.getListActivitiesForComboBox());
    private JComboBox<ComboItem> chantier = new JComboBox<ComboItem>();
    private List<Project> listProjectsForChef;
    private List<Date> datePointage = new ArrayList<Date>();
    private Date columnDate;


    public MyCustomCellRenderer(boolean enabled, int idChef) {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        if (enabled) {
            Project p = new Project();
            p.setChef(idChef);
            listProjectsForChef = p.getListProjectsForSelectedChef();                           
            topPanel = new JPanel();
            Color color = new Color(128, 128, 128);
            chantier.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
            chantier.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), 30));
            Services.setSideBorderColor(chantier, "TOP", color);
            this.add(chantier, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

            hs.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
            hs.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            Services.setSideBorderColor(hs, "RIGHT", color);
            hs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(topPanel.getWidth(), topPanel.getHeight()));
            topPanel.add(hs);
            topPanel.add(activityCombo);
            this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
    //The function that will take the argument
    public void setDatePointage(Date d){
        this.datePointage.add(d);
        this.columnDate = d;
        fillProjectCombobox();//--fill the combo based on the given argument
    }

    public void fillProjectCombobox() {  
        this.chantier.removeAllItems();
        int nbIde = listProjectsForChef.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbIde; i++) {
            String key = Integer.toString(listProjectsForChef.get(i).getId());
            String value = listProjectsForChef.get(i).getDesignation();
            java.sql.Date dateEndMappingChiefProject =  listProjectsForChef.get(i).getDateFin();
            if(dateEndMappingChiefProject != null){
                int compare = dateEndMappingChiefProject.compareTo(this.columnDate);
                if(compare == 1){//---dateEndMappingChiefProject > this.columnDate
                    this.chantier.addItem(new ComboItem(key, value));// ---on ajout les
                }
            }else{
                this.chantier.addItem(new ComboItem(key, value));// ---on ajout les
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shall we guess what the rest of your code looks like?

Comment: @MuratK. The problem that my code is very long, actually I'm using 3 classes for creating this renderer, and the renderer is taking the arguments correctly but it doesn't display it in the combobox.In fact the renderer is taking the last rendere value and apply it to all columns. for example if the combo of the last colmun display [1, 2, 3] all the columns takes the same values!

Comment: Yes, because you are looping over all cells with the same `myArg`

Comment: No no, for each column I put a new argument.

Comment: And where do you declare that mysterious `myArg`?

Comment: I wrote this as example, but I have a list of arguments. But my problem is how can I change the content of my rendere each time I give it a new arg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you're using the same instance of **MyCustomCellRender** for all columns. This will result in every column using the same renderer with the last **myArg** as parameter to render your stuff. What may help is to create a new instance of MyCustomCellRenderer for each column.

E.g:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.nbColumns; i++) {
    MyCustomCellRenderer myRen = new MyCustomCellRenderer //now each column will use it's own renderer instance
    //also: don't forget to set myArg
    myRen.setArg(myArg);
    myJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(myRen);
}
```

Comment: but this will make this application very slow because I'm launching a `SELECT` query each time I create an instance that's I'm trying to avoide this solution.

Comment: You can do the SELECT query somewhere outside the loop once and save it's result to a List or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are looping through all columns and always using the same 'myarg'. There are a number of ways to do this (hard to tell you the best way without seeing your code) but your method could take an additional parameter, like `myarg2`, and then using an if statement (to check i==1):

```
MyCustomCellRenderer myRen = new MyCustomCellRenderer
for(int i = 0; i<table.nbColumns; i++){
  if(i==1){
      myRen.setArg(myArg2);// changed to myArg2
      myJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(myRen);
      continue;
  }
  myRen.setArg(myArg);//----denpending on this argument I fill the combo
  myJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(myRen);
}
```

Comment: @SlimenTunis can we see the current MyCustomCellrenderer class? If it's long just grab the constructor and method signature